# Adding and deleting many-to-many using DbContext API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework and DbContext API do build my application but I am having trouble working with objects with many-to-many relations. A simplified save-method could look like this

```
public void MyObj_Save(MyObj myobj)
{
  DbContext.Entry(myobj).State = EntityState.Added;
  DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code works fine, but if MyObj contains a many-to-many relation this is not saved. I know from using the old POCO API, that I needed to attach the related objects to the context but I cannot find a way to do this correctly with the DbContext API - a simplified example below

```
public void MyObj_Save(MyObj myobj, List<OtherObj> otherObjList)
{
  foreach (OtherObj otherObj in otherObjList)
  {
    DbContext.OtherObj.Attach(otherObj);
    myobj.OtherObj.Add(otherObj);
  }

  DbContext.Entry(myobj).State = EntityState.Added;
  DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get no error, but the relations are not saved. What to do?

Comment: It should work. Is `myobj` saved? But no new rows in the join table?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish by attaching the entities to the context.  If you attach then it "adds an object to the ObjectContext and sets the object to the Unchanged state. In the Unchanged state, the Entity Framework treats the entity key values as final. If more than one entity of a particular type has the same key value, the Entity Framework will throw an exception. To avoid getting the exception, use the AddObject method to attach the detached objects and then change the state appropriately."  See MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx).

Comment: @EmmieGabrielleLewis: He wants to create relationships between a **new** object `myobj` and a list of **existing** objects `otherObjList`. Using `Attach` is correct for this purpose.

Comment: I don't see where an Entity Key is used to define the relationship between the two objects.  Maybe that is what is missing.  Check out this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283138.aspx).

Comment: only myobj gets saved - no new rows are added to the join table.

Comment: @EmmieGabrielleLewis: I expect that the key property is already set in the `otherObj`. Otherwise attaching makes no sense. Also keep in mind that he is using `DbContext` and not `ObjectContext`, so there is no `EntityKey`, just a key property in a POCO class.

Comment: @EmmieGabrielleLewis: Because you are reading articles to regular Entity Framework 4 and not [link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2)

Comment: That's interesting.  Never used the template to generate the proper entities.  I just read a little more about attaching.  Check this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx) out.

Comment: Are `myobj` and the `otherObj` entities are all detached from the context when you enter the method? Something is missing... I've tested your sample code and it works as expected.

Comment: I agree with Slauma.  Everything looks correct according to what I am reading.  Not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: @Slauma: I cannot set a reference key from OtherObj to MyObj as they are "stupid" POCO objects. The objects I send to the method are attached and EntityState is Unchanged. The configuration of my DbContext is, that I have disabled AutoDetectChangesEnabled, LazyLoadingEnabled and ProxyCreationEnabled.

Comment: I can see, that if I call `DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` then my relationship is saved, but this only works when adding new entries, I cannot se a way to remove entries. Also, I could fear that DetectChanges easely could effect other object I am not interested in saving so there must be another way.

Comment: @keysersoze: Can you edit your last two comments into your question. They contain some surprises (`AutoDetectChangesEnabled` set to false is unusual, that the entities are already attached is surprising too (why do you attach them again?), ...).

Comment: @Slauma: I dont think setting AutoDetectChangesEnables set to false is unusual as this makes you control extactly what you want to save and when you want to save. I know that setting state to Added clonflic with what I write, but if I knew exactly what to write I would not be here asking for your help, it was a test as the first code-example did not work - I have also tried setting state to Modifed, but this will update the OtherObj-object and this is not the behavior I am looking for and still it will not insert the relations.

Answer (score 3):

I quote your (important!) comment:

> The objects I send to the method are **attached and EntityState is
>   Unchanged**. The configuration of my DbContext is, that I have **disabled
>   AutoDetectChangesEnabled**...

So, your code would look like this:

```
DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

DbContext.Entry(myobj).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
foreach (OtherObj otherObj in otherObjList)
    DbContext.Entry(otherObj).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

// entering MyObj_Save method here
foreach (OtherObj otherObj in otherObjList)
{
    //DbContext.OtherObj.Attach(otherObj); // does not have an effect
    myobj.OtherObj.Add(otherObj);
}

DbContext.Entry(myobj).State = EntityState.Added;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And this indeed doesn't work because EF doesn't notice that you have changed the relationship between `myobj` and the list of `OtherObj` in the line `myobj.OtherObj.Add(otherObj);` because you have disabled automatic change detection. So, no entries will be written into the join table. Only `myobj` itself will be saved.

You cannot set any state on an entity to put the state manager into a state that the relationship is saved because it is not an entity state which is important here but a relationship state. These are separate entries in the object state manager which are created and maintained by change detection.

I see three solution:

- Set `DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;`
- Call `DetectChanges` manually:

  ```
  //...
  DbContext.Entry(myobj).State = EntityState.Added;
  DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
  DbContext.SaveChanges();
  ```
- Detach the new `myobj` from the context before you set it into `Added` state (this feels very hacky to me):

  ```
  // entering MyObj_Save method here
  DbContext.Entry(myobj).State = EntityState.Detached;
  foreach (OtherObj otherObj in otherObjList)
  //...
  ```

Maybe it is possible - by getting to the `ObjectContext` through the `IObjectContextAdapter` - to modify the relationship entries in the object state manager manually but I don't know how.

In my opinion, this procedure to manipulate entity (and relationship) states manually is not the way you are supposed to work with EF. `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` has been introduced to make working with EF easier and safer and the only recommended situation to disable it is a high performance requirement (for example for bulk inserts). If you disable automatic change detection without need you are running into problems like this which are difficult to detect and it requires advanced knowledge of EF's inner workings to fix those bugs.

Comment: Come on, with all my respect - I know why it do not work but I could not find a solution that would not compromise architecture decisions or could give other pitfalls, e.g. deside exacty which objects to save or not. I am not searching for an easy solution and auto detecting changes can easely give issues in a large application. Anyway - this discusion brings neither of us closer to understand each other so lets end here and also, I did find the solution which I will post as an answer below.

Comment: @keysersoze: Your own answer was included (at least mentioned) as an option in my answer. But: I really dislike it! (but good to know how it works :))

Answer (score 2):

```
public void MyObj_Save(MyObj myobj, List<OtherObj> otherObjList)
{
    DbContext.Entry(myobj).State = EntityState.Added;

    foreach (OtherObj otherObj in otherObjList)
    {
        (((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext)
            .ObjectContext)
            .ObjectStateManager
            .ChangeRelationshipState(myobj, otherObj,
                q => q.OtherObjs, EntityState.Added);
    }

    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Again, it is a simplified and not a real life example!

Comment: I reformatted the code a bit (line breaks) because it's worth to be easily read!